# d3.js how to place custom labels on horizontal log scaled axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing a chart with d3.js using  `d3.scale.log`  for the x axis in combination with a custom labels. Unfortunately the labels run into each other ... any hints on how to make this work?

```
var width = 400;
var x = d3.scale.log().domain([1, 1000]).range([0, width]);

var formatSi = d3.format(".4s");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
        return formatSi(d) + 'Hz'
    });

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");

([1, 3, 6, 9]).forEach(function(d) {
    x.domain([1, Math.pow(10, d)]);
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + d * 2 + "0)")
        .call(xAxis);
});​
```

A working example of this code is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/13/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

figured it out. Trick is to *not* use `.tickFormat` to supply the formatting function, but rather the `.ticks` method which in turn will apply the supplied formatting function to the `.tickFormat`  method of the scale.

```
var width = 400;
var x = d3.scale.log().domain([1, 1000]).range([0, width]);

var formatSi = d3.format(".4s");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
​    .ticks(5,function(d, i) {
        return formatSi(d) + 'Hz';
    });

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");

([1, 3, 6, 9]).forEach(function(d) {
    x.domain([1, Math.pow(10, d)]);
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + d * 2 + "0)")
        .call(xAxis);
});
```

The result is still not entirely satisfying as the system seems to have trouble placeing labels when the ticks are close together ...

Comment: this does not work for me, I have a bar graph with usernames on the x axis, I can't skip "ticks" that would be skipping usernames but showing the data for that name. Aside from that, it also does not work. d3.v3

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, I'm getting `Object function .. has no method 'replace'`.